# How to combine endfloat, markdown formatting and wordwrap in bookdown::pdf_document2 table

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown, kable, kableextra

I am writing a Rmarkdown document using `bookdown::pdf_document2` for which I have a table that needs to do several very specific things, but I simply cannot find the solution to get all of them to work at the same time:

1. The table needs to float to the end of the document as it would with the latex `endfloat` package.
2. The table elements have Markdown bold and italics formatting that should appear correctly in the final PDF document
3. One of the columns of the table has a lot of text that I would like to wrap within the table cell.

I have tried to get these three options to work with all sorts of combinations of `knitr::kable`, `kableExtra::column_spec` and `pander`, but I cannot find a way to get them all going at once. Below I am pasting an example Rmarkdown document with various tests, none of which fully works.

Is there a simple way to get the table to do what I want? Even a good workaround would be acceptable...

Thanks,
David

````
---
title: "Test table formatting"
author: "David M. Kaplan"
date: "5/24/2020"
output: bookdown::pdf_document2
header-includes:
  - \usepackage[tablesfirst]{endfloat}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(tidyverse)
```

# Data

```{r}
df.long = data.frame(
  char = c('*this is some very long text with lots of words that will cause problems with word wrap if it is not properly handled with something like kableExtra*','**b**','~~c~~'),
  num = c(1,2,3))
```

# Kable with format=pandoc

```{r}
knitr::kable(df.long,caption="test1",format="pandoc")
```

**Result:** Handles formatting, but table does not float and no wordwrap.

# Kable with booktab

```{r}
knitr::kable(df.long,caption="test2",booktab=TRUE)
```

**Result:** Floats, but does not handle formatting or do wordwrap.


# kableExtra for wordwrap

```{r}
knitr::kable(df.long,caption="test3",booktab=TRUE) %>%
  kableExtra::column_spec(1,width="30em")
```


**Result:** Table floats and has wordwrap, but does not handle formatting.

# Pander

```{r}
pander::panderOptions("table.alignment.default","left")
pander::pander(df.long,caption="test4")
```

**Result:** Wordwrap and formatting, but does not float.
````

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem. It basically consists of:

1. In the YAML header, add a `header-includes` entry declaring `longtable` to be a float flavor using some LaTeX magic I found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/412829/longtable-with-endfloat).
2. Use pander to format the table to get wordwrap

Specifically, I have the following in the YAML header:

```
header-includes:
  - \usepackage[tablesfirst]{endfloat}
  - \DeclareDelayedFloatFlavour*{longtable}{table}
```

and then the table can be generated with `pander`:

```
pander::panderOptions("table.alignment.default","left")
pander::pander(df.long,caption="test pander",split.cell=50)
```